# Contact via Recycler View and receive from Model Data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the user number to be called and recalled through Recycler View and Model Data

In the adapter, I used the following code but it gives an error

Code in adapter:

`holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

```
            String number=model.getNumber();
            String call="tel:"+number.trim();
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(call));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a15MO.png)

source code:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.Holder> {

    Context context;
    List<Model> models=new ArrayList<>();

    ModelListener modelListener;

    public Adapter(ModelListener modelListener) {
        this.modelListener = modelListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.page_item,parent,false);
        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {
        Model model=models.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.number.setText(model.getNumber());


        holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String number = model.getNumber();
                final Uri numberToCall = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
                final Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberToCall);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name,number;
        ImageView delete,edit,call;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            number=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_number);
            call=itemView.findViewById(R.id.call);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got error on this line `context.startActivity(intent);` beacuse your context is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `requireContext()` to avoid from `null`.

```
holder.call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      final String number = model.getNumber();
      final Uri numberToCall = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
      final Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, numberToCall);
      context.startActivity(intent); //Use back context
}
```

UPDATE:

Add one more parameter for `Context`.

```
public Adapter(ModelListener modelListener, Context context) {
    this.modelListener = modelListener;
    this.context = context;
}
```

When you call your `adapter`, you pass the value `context`. Maybe you will have something like this.

```
final Adapter mAdapter = new Adapter(modelListener, this);
```

Comment: Where should I write RequireContext ?!

Comment: @mrp I have updated the answer. can check

Comment: Some lines were updated correctly
But where do I mean to write the requireContext () method because I get an error and I do not have such a method

Comment: @mrp what is your android studio version?

Comment: android studio version 4.2.1

Comment: Can you check you have latest dependencies? @mrp

Comment: nvm, can I see your `context`? how did you initialize your context? @mrp

Comment: All codes were asked on the question page, please view